# Prolog - Getting the next element in my list of facts in my Tree

Tags: list, recursion, tree, prolog

I have a list of fact as follows:

```
place(63,93,mumbai).
place(61,93,paris).
place(63,97,berlin).
place(33,13,calgary).
place(92,32,tokyo).
```

I want to write a predicate that has the name of the first fact as a root, then adds the next as a child and so on, in a list.
Currently I have written this:

```
buildTree(t(null, null)).
buildTree(t(Name, [H|[]])) :- place(_,_,Name),   buildTree(H).
```

The answer I currently get when I run it is as follows:

```
?- buildTree(T).
T = t(null, null) ;
T = t(mumbai, [t(null, null)]) ;
T = t(mumbai, [t(mumbai, [t(null, null)])]) ;
T = t(mumbai, [t(mumbai, [t(mumbai, [t(null, null)])])])
```

and what I would like to have output is this:

```
?- buildTree(T).
T = t(null, null) ;
T = t(mumbai, null) ;
T = t(mumbai, [t(paris, null)]) ;
T = t(mumbai, [t(paris, [t(berlin, null)])])  (...)
```

any idea what I am missing from my predicate ?

Comment: You're saying you want a tree but the example you're giving is really, basically, a tree version of a linked list where everything is on the left branch. What exactly do you want? A tree or a linked list? And if a tree, what's the rule for balancing the tree, if any?

Comment: Easiest way to do this would be, `findalll(Place, place(_,_,Place), Places), buildTree(Places, Tree)`. Then defined `buildTree([], t(null, null))` and `buildTree([Place|Places], t(Place, SubTree)) :- buildTree(Places, SubTree).`. That would give you a tree that looks like what you're asking for.

Comment: What I mean by tree is basically like a defaultMutableTree in Java, it doesn't have any left/right nodes. you just add to it. What you did works well, but is there a way to do it without using findall? Since I want to be able to just write my predicate without having to use an extra function call.

Comment: `findall/3` is the standard predicate for enumerating solutions to a fact or predicate in Prolog. The reason your predicate (that's what they're called, not  functions) doesn't work is  because when a clause is  re-entered, the new call to the fact starts at the  beginning of the database again. `findall/3` is the  way to  get from facts asserted in a database to a list of terms that can then be processed with standard Prolog list processing.